# Finding area with CGContextEOFillPath

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-graphics

I am interested in using the [CGContextEOFillPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextEOFillPath) feature provided by apple. I am guessing with the way the EOFill works, it probably has a way to take the filled in areas and calculate an area.

So my question is does anyone know of a way to use CGContextEOFillPath and find the area of the filled in sections.

If this isn't something that is easily done, maybe some pointers to a better way of doing this would be helpful. Though I need to use the EO style graphing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "Calculate the area"?

As in calculate the surface area of a complex shape?

It depends on your shapes.

Are they all polygons?

What about circles?

There are well known formulas for calculating the area of a polygon. ([Wikipedia has it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid))  Part of that calculation involves using an ABS() function because shapes drawn "counterclockwise" have the opposite sign as those drawn "clockwise". If you're looking to simulate the EO behavior, you can simply ignore the sign change, because, for you, it's desirable.

If you have more complicated shapes that involve curves, then you need to break the problem down into multiple parts - one part to solve for polygons - one to solve for circles - one to solve for other shapes, etc.

Comment: I was thinking something like i have a graph app. The user sees a function and has to draw the graph of that function. Then it matches the original shape (of the function) to the users drawing with EO and calculating the area that is not exactly like the original shape. the lower the area score the closer they are to the actual or vice versa, the bigger the area size the further away they were to the actual. Does that explain it some?

Comment: but i see what your saying. I might have to investigate into other methods it seems.

Comment: Then you need to lean how to use Integrals: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral